# Can't boot ubuntu 17.10 with usb displaylink monitor?

Tags: usb, 17.10, monitor, displaylink

My usb displaylink monitor works if I have already booted ubuntu with an hdmi monitor plugged into my GTX 1070.  However, if I try booting with just my displaylink monitor plugged in, nothing appears on the screen.

Any suggestions?

Answer (score 0):

It is possible that the driver for the adapter isn't loaded on boot.  I would just unplug and plug in when needed, or add a cheap PCIe GPU for DisplayPort.  I personally wouldn't bother figuring it out.

Nothing appears probably because the OS doesn't detect a monitor and the driver for the adapter won't be loaded.  You'll need a monitor connected to the GPU for normal behaviour.